# Is there a HTML and CSS validator which also checks for ie7 compatibility?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I just made a clean website using HTML4 and CSS. Which worked perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox. I also checked my site using the W3C CSS validator and fixed all the errors and warnings that were displayed. However, when I checked on IE7. The site was totally misaligned and out of place.

Is there a HTML and CSS validator which also checks for ie7 compatibility?

Comment: Not 100% the same perhaps but this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614820/ie7-compatibility-issues can help you a lot.

Comment: There is no question here.  But you are likely seeing one or more IE 7 specific bugs.  Without code or a link, there's not much anyone can do here.

Comment: I think my question is not just specific to my site but related to ie7 bug issue in general.

Comment: Again, without seeing your site, every answer below is just a blind guess.  Therefore, IMHO, this question should be closed.

Answer (score 6):

No, because what you're asking for is not a "validator" but an "invalidator".  IE7 has a number of bugs, and lacks implementation of a number of features.  There's no way for an "invalidator" to know your intent with anything, and thus, can't tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: +1, Yours is the only answer that actually answers the OP's only question.  _"Is there a HTML or CSS validator which also checks for ie7 compatibility?"_

Comment: @Mystere Man you are right. we as a developer can understand that ie7 is an outdated and buggy browser. However, some end users/ visitors still continues using them. So I thought of providing support for them as well.

Answer (score 1):

The route leads along knowing important CSS concepts and browser characteristics. I think there is no such validation service or tool that points out the hacks necessary. :( But there are some magic bullets against bugs in IE7 (e.g. setting the flag hasLayout=true or position:relative). There is a good collection of bug descriptions and reduction here: http://www.brunildo.org/test/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

With your site being a clean html4 and css site, maybe I'm offbase and you've already done this, but just double check that you've included a doctype declaration tag at the beginning of each page. As mentioned above, IE renders in quirks mode without a DOCTYPE specified, and personally i've solved many problems by specifying a doctype in my sites.

Comment: This would be an issue for all versions of IE though, no?  The OP is only having IE 7 issues.

Comment: Yes, that would be a problem for all IE versions, but he never mentioned that other IE versions worked. It seemed to me like he only checked against IE7.

Comment: Doesn't matter.  You did not answer his only question,  _"Is there a HTML or CSS validator which also checks for ie7 compatibility?"_

Comment: I am using dreamweaver software which automatically adds doctype declaration while creating new document.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start using a [CSS reset file](http://www.cssreset.com/). This will reset all default css. These default css settings are different for most browsers. If you do not override them manually, you give the browser the control on your layout. And that's not what we want, aren't we?

Comment: You don't even know what his site looks like.  Maybe his CSS is written such that a reset would be redundant.  Maybe he's encountering an IE 7 specific rendering bug?

Comment: I agree with you, but there's only one way to find out. The SO can use Firebug to see what css rules applies and are not defined by his own css. CSS reset file have saved me already a lot of time and it may help the SO on this problem also. But you're right, no success guaranteed.

Comment: And the OP's only question was,  _"Is there a HTML or CSS validator which also checks for ie7 compatibility?"_  Your answer is not even close.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to upgrade you html to some newer version (html5 if possible or) at least xhtml 1.1,  I think the problem is that IE7 is working in "quirks mode".

More information about [Quirks mode here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)

Comment: XHTML will be more trouble than it's worth. Just use HTML5.

Comment: -1 Why do you think it's a quirks mode issue? IE7 can operate in standards mode as long as there's a valid doc type, even if it's of the HTML4 flavor.

Comment: Since html4 doesn't work properly in ie7 do you think newer versions of html might work well in outdated browser?